# Batch file - Output current cmd output to log?

Tags: batch-file

I know > and >> redirect a command to a file, but how can I get every line of data from the batch file? I have many commands that echo stuff, but I want just 1 that will echo every single command that's been used in the window to a text document.

Batch file:

@echo off
Choice /n /c 12
If %errorlevel%==1 echo hi
Etc..

You know what works perfectly? Right click > edit > select all. HOW THE HELL DO I DO THAT IN CODE

Answer (score 1):

Say your batch script is called myScript.bat, then redirect when you call it:

```
myScript >log.txt
```

You will want to add CALL if used from within another batch script.

You can do the redirection from within your script if you CALL a main routine:

```
@echo off
call :main >log.txt
exit /b

:main
rem rest of your code goes here.
```

Comment: Yeah this kind of works. But I have a whole user-interactive system in my code and I want to get what they already chose in the past

Comment: @user3762093 - I suggest you post some simplified code examples to demonstrate your design, and better describe exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Id recommend tracking Down the Snake.bat program
It logs all user input and game actions.
Have a look through it's code- All the answers to your question are there.

Answer (score 0):

You probably looking for the tee command. It allows for writing to both STDOUT and a textfile at the same time.

More info here : http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/tee-command-examples/